# Is storing AWS policies in the codebase a bad practice?

Tags: amazon-web-services, security

I'm creating an Infrastructure as Code (IaC) codebase for my AWS deployment. In that, I had to store AWS policies in order to execute that via code. In my local machine, I'd set up the Talisman tool to identify secrets before pushing the code to the remote repo. The tool identified certain lines as secrets with high severity.

Eg:

```
Expected file to not to contain hex encoded texts such as: "arn:aws:guardduty:us-west-2:XXXXXXXXXX:detect... 

Potential secret pattern : "s3:x-amz-server-side-encryption-aws-kms-key-id": "arn:aws:kms:us-west-2:XXXXXXXXXX:key/xxxxxxx-xxxxxx-xxxx--xxxx-xxxxxx"
```

Is storing AWS policies like this in our codebase is a security risk?

Comment: No, absolutely no risk, perfectly fine. You of course should check wether it is a good idea to hard-code those values instead of dynamically figuring them out e.g. via data sources.

Comment: Better not use any personal/ sensitive data in your codebase at all. It's highly risky because it indicates your ARN.. You can call these values from another file. What IaC tool do you use? If it's Terraform, you can implement a few way around like, `file("policy_data/arn.json")` or `var.policy_arn`, etc.

Comment: Actually, I have those policies as a separate file. But again, we have to commit that file to the code base, right?